# celery: how to rename a task and route it to a queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Could you please advise on how to assign a custom name on a celery task ?
By default, it gets the module name, but I was wondering in case 
I would like to send a task to a specific queue, how I can achieve that ?

In other words,

given that the related Celery config is like:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery.A', Exchange("xxx"), routing_key='celery.A'),
    Queue('celery.B', Exchange("xxx"), routing_key='celery.B'),
)
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'A': {'queue': 'celery.A', 'routing_key': 'celery.A'},
    'B': {'queue': 'celery.B', 'routing_key': 'celery.B'},
}
```

and there is a function:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def xxx(netelement):
    pass
```

What I would like to achieve is:
if `netelement == A` do `task.name=A` (and then, according to the mapping, route it to queue A)

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the routing in the function body because by definition the task is already executing and has already been routed.

The one obvious solution I can think of is to have your first task delegate to another (asynchronously so it can get routed appropriately).

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def xxx(netelement):
    if netelement == A:
       task_A.delay()
    else:
       task_B.delay()
```

Comment: Note that using `.delay().get()` [may cause a deadlock](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks).

Comment: Sure. That's why I did not suggest it :)